# AWS S3 bucket policy that allows GetObject only from an IP or with Presigned URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

I am trying to create a bucket policy that only allows me to get the objects of a bucket but only if I have a specific IP **OR** if I have the URL with the presigned parameters.

So far I have been trying this with no success (this means I am still unable to access it with the resigned URL if I am not in that SourceIp):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "MyPolicy",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "MyRestriction",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "NotIpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "74.X.X.X/32"
        },
        "Bool": {
          "aws:ViaAWSService": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have also tried with 2 statements for the 2 conditions separated with no success too.

The policy should meet the following conditions:

- If I have that IP, then I should be able to access the bucket https://mybucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/sample.txt but also with the presigned URL.
- If I don't have that IP, then I should only be able to access it with the presigned URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `Deny` on a bucket policy merely overrules an `Allow` policy, and the `Allow` might come from a Bucket Policy or an IAM User/Group/Role. Therefore, rather than using a `Deny` policy (which is always difficult to debug and typically doesn't work as expected), it is typically easier to put conditions on the `Allow` policy that grants access in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by "no success"? Is it failing to grant access, or failing to deny access? More details, please.

Comment: You can check what's presented in S3 access logging and/or CloudTrail, but I don't think there's any way to create a conditional on the client's use of a pre-signed URL in a bucket policy. What *will* be tested is the source IP address, regardless of whether the client used a pre-signed URL, the awscli, or any other client.